# write a query that converts a timestamp to a date and add hours

Tags: mysql, time, timezone, timestamp

I hope someone can help me with this. My knowledge of sql and programming is pretty rudimentary.

I've written a query that looks like this.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(EventStartDate)                     
FROM mytable
```

This does what I need -converting a timestamp to a readable date, but the time is 5 hours off. I guess my timestamp is GMT and I'm in -5:00. Is there some way to write this that adds 5 hours as well as converting to a readable date?

I appreciate any help I can get with this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CAST(EventStartDate AS datetime), '%Y %M %D')  AS Date FROM mytable;

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CAST(EventStartDate AS datetime), '%Y %m %d') AS Date FROM mytable;


SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(EventStartDate,'+00:00','-05:00'),'%Y %m %d') AS Date FROM mytable;


SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(EventStartDate,'+00:00','-05:00'),'%Y %M %D') AS Date FROM mytable;

-- with time

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CAST(EventStartDate AS datetime), '%Y %M %D %h:%i:%s') AS Date_time FROM mytable;

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CAST(EventStartDate AS datetime), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') AS Date_time FROM mytable;


SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(EventStartDate,'+00:00','-05:00'),'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') AS Date_time FROM mytable;


SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(EventStartDate,'+00:00','-05:00'),'%Y %M %D %h:%i:%s') AS Date_time FROM mytable;
```

A readable format is somewhat unspecific so I have tried some formats that your might like. You might even use a different language so this is very difficult to answer. For example you could use `SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(EventStartDate,'+00:00','-05:00'),'%Y %M %D') FROM mytable;` to get your date in spanish ([PHP/MySQLi: SET lc_time_names and DATE_FORMAT() into a mysqli query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769060/php-mysqli-set-lc-time-names-and-date-format-into-a-mysqli-query)).  Or if you use PHP you could use it to reformat in your own language.

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3762/50)

In the you title you say you need to convert timestamp into a date. However, you use from_unixtime so I have the impression that you might be using VARCHAR or INT as you column type. In that case you should try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(EventStartDate_INT),'+00:00','-05:00') AS Date_time FROM mytable;

SELECT CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(EventStartDate_VARCHAR),'+00:00','-05:00') AS Date_time FROM mytable;

SELECT date_format(CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(EventStartDate_INT),'+00:00','-05:00'),'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') AS Date_time FROM mytable;

SELECT date_format(CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(EventStartDate_VARCHAR),'+00:00','-05:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') AS Date_time FROM mytable;
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23e04/19)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) you should be able to add 5 hours to a date like so:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(EventStartDate) + INTERVAL 5 HOUR FROM mytable ;
```

or

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(EventStartDate), INTERVAL 5 HOUR) FROM mytable ;
```