# How to use lc_time_names in a VIEW?

Tags: mysql

I have a `view` that returns the day of the week, it is returning the day of the week in English.

I know that by doing `SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR';` Works perfectly, but I wanted to leave this command inside the `"VIEW"`

How could he do that?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't do that since `lc_time_names` is a global variable. But yes you can include it in a `*.sql` file though probably but not as part of `VIEW` definition.

You can even set the same from your server side code and then perform `select * ...` from the view. An PHP example here: [PHP/MySQLi: SET lc_time_names and DATE_FORMAT() into a mysqli query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769060/php-mysqli-set-lc-time-names-and-date-format-into-a-mysqli-query)

Comment: I needed to use lc_time_names within the same view, because my view is ready.

Comment: @William, unfortunately you can't and that's what mentioned in answer.