# Running two SQL queries on one php page (SET + SELECT)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I need translate to "pt_br" the currently month and this code are working like a charm on phpmyadmin:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR';
SELECT MONTHNAME(CURDATE()) AS `Mes`  
                              FROM trabalho_v2
```

Someone may help me use the "SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR';" on my php code?

```
<?php
// Show current month
include 'conection.php';                      

$sql .= "SELECT MONTHNAME(CURDATE()) AS `Mes` FROM trabalho_v2 ";                       
$busca  = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);                      
$dados  = mysqli_fetch_array($busca);
$mes = $dados['Mes'];
```

I tried to create a new querie to inject only this stretch but it didn't work:

```
<?php
// Show current month
include 'conection.php';                      
$sql = "SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR';";  
$sql .= "SELECT MONTHNAME(CURDATE()) AS `Mes` FROM trabalho_v2 ";                       

$busca  = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);                      
$dados  = mysqli_fetch_array($busca);
$mes = $dados['Mes'];
```

Comment: what you mean with didnt work?

Comment: maybe this solution will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769060/php-mysqli-set-lc-time-names-and-date-format-into-a-mysqli-query

Comment: i tried use the $mysqli->query("SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES'");  but dont worked too

Comment: when i say didnt work i means it dont translate the month on pt_br on my dashboard

Comment: Have you tried to call `mysqli_query()` twice, first with the `SET ...` and then with the `SELECT ...`?

Comment: use only this in your case: mysqli_query($conexao,"SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR'");

Comment: Worked! Thanks very much Mubashar!!

Answer (score 1):

These are two separate queries. You can't concatenate them together. You have to execute them separately.

```
<?php

// Show current month
include 'conection.php';
                      
$sql = "SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR'";
mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

$sql = "SELECT MONTHNAME(CURDATE()) AS `Mes` FROM trabalho_v2";
$busca = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
$dados = mysqli_fetch_array($busca);
$mes = $dados['Mes'];
```

I also strongly encourage you to use OO style:

```
<?php

// Show current month
include 'conection.php';
                      
$sql = "SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR'";
$conexao->query($sql);

$sql = "SELECT MONTHNAME(CURDATE()) AS `Mes` FROM trabalho_v2";
$busca = $conexao->query($sql);
$dados = $busca->fetch_array();
$mes = $dados['Mes'];
```